# Firebase: notify app uers when data in a json file changes

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I have successfully built an android app for my WordPress blog. The app retrieves the list of posts from an online jSON file, parses it and populates RecyclerView with the data. The last bit of work is notifying the users when I post new content to blog and the JSON file changes.

Please, do you have any idea how I might achieve this?

Comment: you should just use the rest API and just update the data at the db. Realtime database make all the client update itself therefore a good solution for you.

Comment: @Shubhank, This realm of Android development is still unfamiliar to me. Hence your comment is all Greek to me. Please can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the push services on both ends (android and firebase).check firebase's docs for how to implement their service.

push services automatically notifies (or posts , you can do whatever you like when the event is fired) the users subscribed to the service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but please can you write a sample code to illustrate your answer?